# Expanding Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

For some reason Ubuntu decided not to utilize the 100GB I cleared for it, and installed itself with only 28GB of space. I only discovered this now, after it started bugging me about running out of space.

I've tried googling my issue, but it appears that it's a somewhat dangerous process that heavily depends on the exact situation, so I thought I'd be better off asking you guys for help.

I have two physical drives, one for Windows only and another for storage/Ubuntu. The partitions on the second drive looks like this.

[image: this]

Comment: Maybe? It is often mentioned that it is only an easy task with adjacent partitions, while I have a 1MiB grub2 partition separating them. Can gparted handle that from a live-cd?

Comment: GParted can handle resizing non-adjacent partitions from a live CD/USB.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll attempt the top solution mentioned in your link.

Comment: The answer actually did not work. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401002/rearrange-partitions-in-gparted-to-extend-a-partition) answer mentioned that on uefi I could apparently just delete the grub2 partition, which I did. It also mentioned that he reinstalled grub2 again, which I haven't done, but Ubuntu still boots just fine. Do you think that step is necessary?

Comment: If both Ubuntu and Windows boot properly with reinstalling grub2, then that step is unnecessary.